# How to implement pie chart with x-axis and y-axis in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

Hi I am trying to implement pie chart but with x and y-axis but I am not getting it how to do it...single pie chart I can do but how to implement like below image.

[image: Pie Chart with axis]

Comment: what do you put on the y-axis?

Comment: it can be blank

Comment: This isn't possible with chart.js.  I would recommend you handle the x axis in your image outside of the scope of chart.js.  Just position your `canvas` elements side by side, create 3 chart.js pie charts, and use HTML/CSS to draw your x-axis, x-axis labels, and handle all the positioning.  With this approach you will need to also use a custom legend.  Refer to [this example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/PpJjWK) that demonstrates custom legends

Comment: yes I already did show.